# How do I skip a test_utility file when running Python unittest?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I have a utilities package, and am including tests for some of the utilities. However, one of the directories has a bunch of django TestCase specific reusable classes, and it keeps running and failing when I run:

`python -m unittest`

The file's name is testutils.py and is for other Django apps to import and use, not to be tested itself. Is there a settings or skip file where I can tell my package not to look at that file when running tests?

Comment: Rename the file to something not beginning with `test`?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to name that file something that it isn't.

Comment: How are the files organised? Can you use the `-k` [command line option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-options)? Or the `-s`, `-p`, and `-t` options for [discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)?

Answer (score 0):

`unittest` defaults to checking files that match the following glob for tests: `test*.py`. As you can see, `testutils.py` matches that pattern and so is always searched for tests -- even if they are only meant to be stubs.

You need to either rename `testutils.py` to something that does not match this pattern or change the glob pattern that `unittest` uses to discover test files. As an example, you could name all your test files like `test_*.py` (eg. `test_foo.py`) and then run your tests like:

```bash
python -m unittest discover -p 'test_*.py'
```

The underscore in the pattern will match things like `test_foo.py`, but will stop it from matching `testutils.py`.

One file structure might look like:

```
./main.py
./util.py
./tests/util.py
./tests/test_main.py
./tests/test_util.py
```

All test files whether they contain tests or utility functions and classes are contained under the `tests/` directory. Thus, we know that `tests/util.py` contains utilities for tests rather than being part of the main application's code. And that `test_util.py` is a file that is being used to test code in `./util.py`.

#### Side note

`util` isn't a very good descriptor for a module or file. It basically means "junk that I can't really think of a good name for". From a brief description of your tests maybe something like `django_test_harness` might be appropriate.